# AT Command and its voice output

Tags: modem

How can I get the voice stream of the other caller? When you dial using AT command through the terminal,  it signifies that it is ringing,  but when the call is answered,  no sound is heard.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the AT command set.  There are commands for turning up the volume and turning the speaker on or off, etc that you may need to set.  This one is a blast from the past and takes me back!  Do you hear it dial?

http://www.computerhope.com/atcom.htm

Comment: What I want to do exactly,  Is to forward the voice over Web..  For example: running a live streaming audio website of the call...